# Complex partial fractions of order 2

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I don't really understand what he means by preliminary linear transformation.
 I assume you start with $$\frac{az^2+bz+c}{(z+\alpha)^2}$$

But what linear transformation changes that into

$$a'z^2+b'z+c'$$

Then what linear transformation is he using to go from

$$a'z^2+b'z+c'=a'(z+\frac{b'}{2a'})^2+c'-\frac{b'^2}{4a'}$$

To

$$z^2$$

Because it doesn't feel like these transformations are "linear."

Comment: Who is “he”? That it, what's the source that you're quoting?

Comment: Perhaps it's just this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249427/why-displaystyle-fz-fracazbczd-a-b-c-d-in-mathbb-c-is-a-linear

Comment: @HansLundmark  Lars alhfors : complex analysis

Comment: Yes, then that's it. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009319/why-is-the-mobius-transform-called-a-linear-transform.